# How can text in a react navigation 5 headerRight be updated based on state?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

When the user clicks the 'Edit' button in the react-navigation 5 headerRight, I would like the text to toggle to show 'Done', but it seems the navigation options. don't have access to the current state. How can this be updated to work?

```
import React, {useState, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function ListScreen({navigation}){
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
      navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setEditMode(!editMode) }>
            <Text>{editMode ? 'Done' : 'Edit'}</Text>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        ),
      });
    }, [navigation]);

  return (....)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the editMode as a dependency for the layoutEffect hook.
Without that the hook will run only when 'navigation' param changes. Change it like below.

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
      navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setEditMode(!editMode) }>
            <Text>{editMode ? 'Done' : 'Edit'}</Text>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        ),
      });
    }, [navigation,editMode]);
```